# How to change the registry value of remote system using C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

Hai every one
I am developing an windows application in which i have to block the removable storage devices such as pendrives.I found that its possible by changing the registry value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor,start value to 4.But the problem is I have to block it on remote systems too.Can any one suggest me how to change the value of registry of remote system using c# with a code or sites where i can i find the code for this.

Comment: It's a bone fide programming question, but in case it doesn't find a response, you may want to check on serverfault.com (or maybe superuser.com) where people probably know of readily made programs which do this kind of administrative tasks.

Comment: how much access do you have to these remote machines? And what is the reason for needing to block them on remote machines (for example, I do this for secure academic testing, but I wouldn't recommend my approach as an appropriate solution to all problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .net way is to use [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx).

An alternative would be to use WMI. [There are lots of examples on Google for reading values](http://www.google.com/search?q=ManagementBaseObject+default%3AStdRegProv+GetStringValue+c%23); replacing GetStringValue with [SetStringValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393600%28VS.85%29.aspx) (or SetDWORDValue, etc.) should do what you want.

Comment: Or how about PowerShell? http://mybsinfo.blogspot.com/2007/01/powershell-remote-registry-and-you-part.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at the Remote Registry Service and make an RPC call.

MSDN description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940121(WinEmbedded.5).aspx
MSDN example using RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **Remote Registry** service running on remote machine. Then you can use **WMI** to connect the registry. Here is a code sample script from [this site](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/11/view.asp?id=7113):

```
Dim strComputer
Dim strUserName
Dim strPassword
Dim objLocator
Dim objService
Dim objRegistry

strComputer = "somesys" 
strUserName = "somename" 
strPassword = "somepw" 

Set objLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
Set objService = objLocator.ConnectServer( strComputer, _
"Root\Default", strUserName, strPassword ) 

objService.Security_.impersonationlevel = 3 

Set objRegistry = objService.Get( "StdRegProv" )

'Do something here like retrieving or setting values.

Set objRegistry = Nothing
Set objLocator = Nothing
Set objService = Nothing
```

you can get many valuable results by googling for "using WMI to modify remote registry"